# Searching for jobs using jenkins-pipeline in sandbox mode

Tags: groovy, sandbox, jenkins-pipeline

I am working with the Jenkins-pipeline groovy scripts; but I must work in sandbox mode.

Is there a way to find all jobs matching a naming pattern?

In non-sandbox mode it is possible to write

```
def theJobs=Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(Job);
    for(def i=0;i<theJobs.size;i++)
    {
        def jobName= theJobs[i].getName()
        if( jobName.toUpperCase() =~ 'myregexp-pattern')
        { ...
```

but in the sandbox this give a security exception: 
    RejectedAccessException: unclassified field java.lang.Class instance

How can the same effect be achieved in a way that is sandbox compatible?

Comment: I suppose you can't/don't want to use admin functionnality `In-process Script Approval` to manually approve the specific sandbox security exception ?

Comment: This does not even appear in the approval list.

But in writing this response I found he solution:
The property ".instance" never appears in the approval list so I was blocked. 
However, the method "getInstance()" does make it appear so I can get approval and continue.

Answer (score 1):

Using the method ".getInstance()" instead of the property ".instance" makes it appear in the Script Approval list. Once approved, the script runs.